# How to get php curl Verbs PUT, DELETE, PATCH and GET for REST API service

Tags: php, web-services, api, rest, curl

I create a web API service for customers details. And how can i getting token and verbs PUT, DELETE, PATCH and GET for verifying API call and giving that's information.?

```
$URL = 'http://localhost/rest_api_project1/customer-api/v1/user/A2/items';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);  //Post Fields

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


//--Setting header.
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Apple-Tz: 0';
$headers[] = 'X-Apple-Store-Front: 143444,12';';
$headers[] = 'Host: www.example.com';
$headers[] = 'Referer: http://www.example.com/index.php'; //Your referrer address
$headers[] = 'Token: asf987a9sdf89asd989879asdf98as7d9-sadf8asd-sdf8a9088a';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print $server_output;
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is about but maybe you will find [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](http://docs.php.net/reserved.variables.server) helpful.

Comment: You also look like you have a syntax error in that code. The colour change should give you a big clue where.

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is working thanx for answering me... :)

Comment: FYI, a simple example for a basic rest api in PHP can be found here: https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/blob/master/extras/core.php

Comment: Thanx.. very helpfull